# JavaScript not sending to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with three inputs  and a php file with a function `conv()` with takes three paramater. I want when a user type in a textfeild( this text filed has onlick function called `post())` the form data should be posted to php and results from php to be displayed in a filed with ID results. I have my code but its not working. Can any one help.

```
             <script>
function post(){
         var hr = new XMLhttpRequest();
        var url = "curencyconvert.php";
        var param = document.getElementsById("param").value;
        var param2 = document.getElementsById("param2").value;
        var param3 = document.getElementsById("param3").value;
        var vals = "param="+param+"&param2="+param2+"& param3"+param3;
        hr.open("POST",url,true);
        hr.sendRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange= function(){
                if(hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
                    var return_data = hr.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = return_data;
                    }

        }
    hr.send(vals);
    }
</script>
```

And my PHP file is this:

```
              function Conv($param,$param2,$param3){
                 $restults= $_POST['param'];
                  return $restults;

            }
```

Comment: What is not working? You need to narrow down the problem.

Comment: am geting no response from the php file. it seems not data is sent to php

Comment: The code you posted only contains a function. Are you actually calling that function in your php script?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling the post function written in Javascript
and  function  in PHP should echo instead of return and also ...

```
if(isset($_POST)){
//Calling the defined function here
Conv($_POST['param'], $_POST['param2'], $_POST['param3']);
}
```

should  be added to the php file

Answer (score 0):

I am going for jquery don't forget to include jquery.js file.

```
function post(){
    var param = $("#param").val();
    var param2 = $("#param2").val();
    var param3 = $("#param3").val();
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'curencyconvert.php',
            data: {param: param, 
                  param2: param2,
                  param3: param3
                   },
            success: function (response) {
             $("#results").html(response);
            }
        });
}
```

And in curencyconvert.php you take those values and pass it to the function

```
  $param=$_POST['param'];
  $param2=$_POST['param2'];
  $param3=$_POST['param3'];
  Conv($param,$param2,$param3);

   function Conv($param,$param2,$param3)
       {
         $results= $param.",".$param2.",".$param3;
         return $results;
        }
```

**Don't use direct post variable use some filter for mysql injection**